# How do I ensure that a terminal remains scrollable?

Tags: linux, tty

On my tty terminals (1-6), I lose text when I move away from it and back (i.e. pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Pg Up</kbd> doesn't reveal any scrolled-off text). How can I recover this text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, it's just lost. The Linux console only stores history until you change to a different console. If you want to keep more history, use Screen.

Comment: or http://tmux.sf.net

Comment: @akira: or Emacs…

Comment: Go not to the elves^H^H^H Internet for counsel, for they will say both yes and no...and maybe and you should use Emacs... ;-)